# Generate and download QR Code from string with QRious - additional white spaces

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I'm trying to generate and download QR Codes in my application using QRious (https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrious).

I have to pass a string of any size to my function and generate a 100px X 100px sized QR Code, without any paddings, convert it to a base64 .png image and download it as .png.

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
getQrCodeImgData (obj) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      var qr = new QRious({
        value: obj.str,
        padding: 0,
        size: 100
      })
      return resolve({fileName: obj.fileName, imgData: qr.toDataURL().split(',')[1]})
    })
  }
```

Everything works fine, and I can download my .png image, that has 100px X 100px, but my QR Code isn't filling the whole image dimensions, leaving white spaces in the image.

You can check an example below, inspect the image to view the white spaces:

[image]

I just can't eliminate those white spaces using QRious. I've tested multiple configurations when creating the QR Code with "new QRious({})".

Does anyone know how can I overcome this issue using QRious or any other js QR Code library?

Thanks!

Comment: There are several sizes of QR codes, but all of them have a specific number of "QR pixels". The one you're showing has 37x37 "QR pixels", and they have to be crisp. Thus the ideal image size for a QR code like that is a multiple of 37, for instance 74 or 111 pixels. Fitting them into 100 pixels requires stretching the 74x74 pixels image using a bilinear or nearest neighbor filter. Both of those are less than ideal for the purposes of a QR code. Check the live codepen and you will see that QUious uses a bit off padding so the threshold is at 116: https://codepen.io/neocotic/pen/YQzmBm

Comment: That's it, thank you very much! It's all about fitting my QR Code in a multiple of 37 pixels sized square. But now another question comes up: how can I preview the number of "QR pixels"? Does it have any direct relation to the content's length? Thanks again!

Comment: I've found this explanation: http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html. As my content is a 94 length binary string and I'm going to use a L damage level, my QR Codes will have 37x37 modules, the threshold being 106 binary characters for this same module size. If I have random string lengths, I think I should implement those thresholds in my code as constants and calculate the size based on those constants. Do you think this would be the right approach to always achieve QR Codes without those extra white spaces? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sounds like it should work fine.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, Chris!